# How can I add Taxonomy Term to a Node's Breadcrumb?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

The Node has attached a single Term.

Current breadcrumbs rendered

```
[HOME] >> [NODE_TITLE]
```

Want to render like this.

```
[HOME] >> [TERM] >> [NODE_TITLE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @No Sssweat is right. I think you need to built a custom module for this.
[Add Taxonomy Term to a Node's Breadcrumb in Drupal 8](https://gist.github.com/jonpugh/ccaeb01e173abbc6c88f7a332d271e4a)

Answer (score 5):

Themers who don't want to use a custom module to implement a BreadcrumbBuilder can change the breadcrumbs in a preprocess hook.

Example how you can add a link before the last link:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $breadcrumb = &$variables['breadcrumb'];
  $lastlink = array_pop($breadcrumb);
  array_push($breadcrumb, [
    'text' => 'New Link',
    'url' => '/newlink',
  ]);
  array_push($breadcrumb, $lastlink);
}
```

If you add a taxonomoy term from a node you would have to add both as cache tags and a cache context on the url to make this work.

Comment: I like your idea to achieve the same. :)

Comment: I've tried to leverage the same, can you please review https://goo.gl/1nmkEU :)

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha, this looks good, you could add an answer with your code

Answer (score 5):

We can implement custom breadcrumb either via `module` or via `HOOK_preprocess_breadcrumb`.

Via `HOOK_preprocess_breadcrumb`:

Add this in your `YOURTHEME.theme`

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_preprocess_breadcrumb().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $variables['breadcrumb']) {
    $breadcrumb = &$variables['breadcrumb'];
    if (!empty($node->field_tags->entity)) {
      $term_url = $node->field_tags->entity->toLink();
      $node_url = array_pop($breadcrumb);
      array_push($breadcrumb, $term_url);
      array_push($breadcrumb, $node_url);
      // Implementing Cache.
      $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = "url.path";
      $variables['#cache']['tags'][] = "node:{$node->nid->value}";
    }
  }
}
```

Via `module`:

In `custom_breadcrumb.module` file

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_breadcrumb;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Class Breadcrumbs.
 *
 * @package Drupal\custom_breadcrumb
 */
class Breadcrumbs implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {
  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return $route_match->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical' && $route_match->getParameter('node') instanceof NodeInterface;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();

    // By setting a "cache context" to the "url", each requested URL gets it's
    // own cache. This way a single breadcrumb isn't cached for all pages on the
    // site.
    $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(["url"]);

    // By adding "cache tags" for this specific node, the cache is invalidated
    // when the node is edited.
    $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(["node:{$node->nid->value}"]);

    // Add "Home" breadcrumb link.
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Home'), '<front>'));

    // Given we have a taxonomy term reference field named "field_tags" and that
    // field has data, add that term as a breadcrumb link.
    if (!empty($node->field_tags->entity)) {
      $breadcrumb->addLink($node->field_tags->entity->toLink());
    }
    return $breadcrumb;
  }

}
```

and then in `custom_breadcrumb.services.yml`

```
services:
  custom_breadcrumb.breadcrumbs:
    class: Drupal\custom_breadcrumb\Breadcrumbs
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 100 }
```

Both the ways are achievable, if your question is which one should be followed and which one should be referred as a **best practice**, refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238962/3808

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more parametrized theme code example for non-node entities with taxonomy parents, made by combining [Rishi Kulshreshtha's code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/239154/7177) with [taxonomy parents addition by mfrosch](https://gist.github.com/jonpugh/ccaeb01e173abbc6c88f7a332d271e4a#gistcomment-2127175)

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_breadcrumb(array &$vars) {
  // proper taxonomy breadcrumbs for Commerce Products through field_category
  $entity_type = 'commerce_product'; // TODO: change or verify
  $taxonomy_field_name = 'field_category'; // TODO: change or verify

  if (($entity = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter($entity_type)) && $vars['breadcrumb']) {
    $cache_tag = "{$entity_type}:{$entity->product_id->value}"; // TODO: change or verify

    $breadcrumb = &$vars['breadcrumb'];
    if (!empty($entity->$taxonomy_field_name->entity)) {
      $node_url = array_pop($breadcrumb);

      $term = $entity->$taxonomy_field_name->entity;
      $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
        ->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
      $parents = $storage->loadParents($term->id());
      if (!empty($parents)) {
        foreach ($parents as $index => $parent) {
          array_push($breadcrumb, $parent->toLink());
        }
      }
      array_push($breadcrumb, $term->toLink());

      array_push($breadcrumb, $node_url);

      // Implementing Cache.
      $vars['#cache']['contexts'][] = "url.path";
      $vars['#cache']['tags'][] = $cache_tag;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking a quick peek in contrib modules, as of this writting, there doesn't seem anything that you can use for D8.

Here is a creative quick and easy solution/suggestion:

With Views and bit of Rewrite Results/Template file + CSS you could create your own breadcrumbs view block.