# How do I programmatically remove one breadcrumb link?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

in Drupal 7 I could just use `array_pop($breadcrumb)`, but in Drupal 8 the breadcrumb is an object and I don't see a method for removing the last element.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can still do this in a preprocess hook, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226538/how-can-i-add-taxonomy-term-to-a-nodes-breadcrumb/226560#226560

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 are more or less the same in some aspects.

If you use `preprocess_breadcrumb` in your theme, you would do

```
function my_theme_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  array_pop($variables['breadcrumb']);
  ...
}
```

You could also solve this in the template file, by skipping the first item in `{{ breadcrumb }}`

If you want module only solution, you could swap the breadcrumb service with your own thing.

Comment: Is it `$variables['breadcrumb']` or `$variables['links']`?

Comment: @kiamlaluno `$variables['breadcrumb']` is the correct one, links is what the original preprocess uses to generate the breadcrumb. Any theme overwriting it will act after this has happened, so they should alter breadcrumb instead of links.

Comment: Thank you. I was just checking the approved suggestion edit (which was not approved by you) was correct, since it was changing the meaning of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a BreadcrumbBuilder, and try to remove a Link already added, you can't. Unless you create a custom Breadcrumb class, to add a new method or override an existing one.

My solution was this :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;

/**
 * Blablabla.
 */
class BreadcrumbCustom extends Breadcrumb {

  /**
   * Sets the breadcrumb links.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Link[] $links
   *   The breadcrumb links.
   * @param bool $force
   *   Boolean to indicate if you should force to override the existing links.
   *   Use with caution.
   *
   * @return $this
   *
   * @throws \LogicException
   *   Thrown when setting breadcrumb links after they've already been set.
   */
  public function setLinks(array $links, $force = FALSE) {
    if (!empty($this->links) && !$force) {
      throw new \LogicException('Once breadcrumb links are set, only additional breadcrumb links can be added.');
    }

    $this->links = $links;

    return $this;
  }

}
```

and inside the BreadcrumbBuilder :

```
$links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
unset($links[1]);
$breadcrumb->setLinks($links, TRUE);
```

Comment: The parameter _force_ does not exist anymore (at least in 8.5.5).

Comment: Since it's a custom class, with override of a method, it doesn't matter ^^

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. Of course you are right. I thought you were talking about the core breadcrumb.