# How to use unique taxonomy term for nodes in Drupal 7?

Tags: path-aliases, taxonomy-terms

I have unique categories assigned to nodes via taxonomy module. now I want the path to be something like this:

```
root/taxonomy-vocabulary/taxonomy-term/node-titel
```

Any ideas?

This question has already been [asked for Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226538/how-can-i-add-taxonomy-term-to-a-nodes-breadcrumb) but I am running Drupal 7. So there might be a module or setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and set template for your node's path as you want on page admin/config/search/path/patterns

In this case You can use all this tokens with taxonomy term names, something like that:
[node:taxonomy-vocabulary-1:name] etc. List with all this tokens is on admin/config/search/path/patterns page